# Can not import and use DirectorySearch in atom.io

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm trying to build a [package](https://github.com/CodeMySky/java-importer) for atom editor, I need to search for all local files in the project. 
From https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.2/DirectorySearch I see DirectorySearch is an interesting class to search for specific text in local files.

There is little documentation on the page. I tried `{DirectorySearch} = require 'atom'` and `new atom.DirectorySearch()`. But they are not working, said "DirectorySearch is undefined".

I searched in atom's repository, but it seems that they only defined it. There is no usage of DirectorySearch. I also searched on Google and Stack Overflow but with no luck.

I'm using Version 1.0.2 on Mac OSX 10.

Can someone tell me how to import and use this class?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-import-and-use-directorysearch-in-atom/19205

> Looking at the source it doesn't seem you can require it, but there's an instance of `DefaultDirectorySearcher` created in the workspace and available at `atom.workspace.defaultDirectorySearcher` that is used in the scan method as a fallback when a searcher for a directory haven't been specified.
>
> If you want to search text in files, `atom.workspace.scan` should be enough.
>
> You can also register a custom directory searcher using the `atom.directory-searcher` service, as far as I can tell, the object needs to implement the following methods to comply to the searcher interface:
>
> -`canSearchDirectory (directory:Directory) -> Boolean`
>
> -`search(directories:Array, regex:RegExp, searchOptions:Object) -> CancellablePromise`
>
> The `DirectorySearch` class that appears in the docs is actually the `CancellablePromise` returned by the directory searcher.